# Add weights for two predictors in lm() in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lm

I'm fitting a two-degree polynomial using three variables: the response (y) and two predictors (x, u). That is:

```
fit <- lm(y~polym(x, u, degree = 2, raw=TRUE))
```

However the input data I'm using to fit have standard deviations, I mean, my initial dataframe (df) is like:

```
y      sig_y      x       sig_x       u       sig_u

3.45   0.03     2.58     0.27      -1.21    0.015
5.23   0.14     3.05     0.13      -0.10    0.01
4.16   0.11     3.36     0.18       0.44    0.09
...    ...      ...      ...        ...     ...
```

I would like to take into account these standard deviations into the fit, so I want to add weights for each variable.

I know there's the function *weights* for the lm and glm functions, but this is just for one variable, like:

```
fit0 <- lm(y~x, weights=1/(df$sig_x)**2)
```

and I'm looking for something like (just the idea...):

```
fit <- lm(y~polym(x, u, degree = 2, raw=TRUE), weights1=1/(df$sig_x)**2, weights2=1/(df$sig_u)**2)
```

How can I achieve that? Actually, if I can take into account also the response standard deviations (sig_Y), it would be even better...

Comment: the `weights` argument does not apply on just one variable, but on all the rows of a `data.frame`. It means that when a datum has a weight of 3, it is similar to observe 3 times this particular datum in your data.

Comment: @Mamoun Benghezal. From your answer I understand that 'weights' associates a weight for each observation (yi.... yj), no matter how variables I need to define this observation (x,y,u).  So, is there (or do you know) another function or another way to do the fit so I can take into account the standard deviations of each variable of my input data in the fit?